# Unable to compile TypeScript in VS Code because there's a space in the locally installed `tsc` path

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsc

I have created a TypeScript project on VS Code. I have installed TypeScript compiler locally in the project itself.

The path contains space so, when I try to build the project the command is

`c:\Space in path\src\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd -p "c:\Space in path\src\tsconfig.json"`

And this throws error.

> The term 'c:\Space' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

When I run the command from my command prompt **with** double quotes

`"c:\Space in path\src\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd" -p "c:\Space in path\src\tsconfig.json"`

It runs and gives me JS output.

Any way to make VS Code put double quotes around `tsc` path?

**Update 1**

I am running build task from VS Code by going to "Tasks > Run Build Tasks" and then selecting `tsc:build - tsconfig.json`. My `tsconfig.json` looks like this.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", 
        "outDir": "scripts/"
    }    
}
```

Comment: do you have this configured as a task in vs code? if so try to add the needed quotes with \"

Comment: I haven't configured tasks for it. How do I do that?

Comment: well.. how do you run it now? jus tthe command prompt? if so, adding the quotes is the way to go. it's a command prompt limitation.

Comment: I am using  "Tasks > Run Build Tasks". I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: and how does the tasks file look?

Comment: There is no tasks file. I am new to TypeScript/VS Code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157914/discussion-between-toskv-and-naveen).

Comment: The issue appears whenever VS Code executes a task where a .cmd file is located in a path that includes spaces. My tasks.json file is quite simple, including a line for "type": "gulp"; the rest is done by VS Code (executing gulp.cmd in my npm directory - which includes spaces!). I haven't found a solution for this.